# nativescript-vue navigateTo outside of vue component

Tags: javascript, nativescript-vue

Hello I have a problem that I solved yesterday but it appears again.

I try to use a function for routing between my vue pages.

routes.js

```js
import Page from '../components/Page'

const routes = {
    Page
}

export const vue = routes
```

Navigator.js

```js
import { topmost } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame'

function navigateTo (page) {
  topmost().currentPage.__vuePageRef__.$navigateTo(page)
}

export { navigateTo }
```

Vue Page:

```js
import {navigateTo} from "../router/navigator";

  created: function() {
    navigateTo(routes.vue.Page);
  }
```

but it throws me the error

> System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentPage' of undefined

I remember that I have solved the problem yesterday by changing the navigateTo 'function' to a 'default function'.

But this time it throws me an error called:

> System.err: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

when im passing the **routes.vue.Page**

I would appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't precisely fix the errors you get, but has worked fine yet.

router.js

```js
import login from "./views/Login";
import home from "./views/Home";

export default {
    login,
    home
}
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import router from "./router";

Vue.prototype.$goTo = function(to, props, params) {
    if (!router[to]) return;

    this.$navigateTo(router[to], {
        props,
        ...params // clearHistory, backstackVisible
    });
}
```

Component.vue

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        goToLogin() {
            this.$goTo("login");
        },
        goToHome(prop) {
            this.$goTo("home", { prop }, { clearHistory: true });
        }
    }
}
```